# Sql finding two columns for values

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables joined with inner join with a column
Now rows would have

```
A   B
C   D
E   G
P   Q
Z   F
```

This row I need to compare with Master Relation Table

```
Column1     Column2
A       B
D       C
E       F
```

So based on the above condition I need to show records in a report

```
A   B   Do Not Show
C   D   Do Not Show
E   G   Show
P   Q   Show
Z   F   Show
```

Comment: You probably want a LEFT JOIN followed by the INNER JOIN

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T1.Col2,
       CASE WHEN T2.Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Do Not Show' ELSE 'Show' END AS Result
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON 
     (T1.Col1=T2.Column1 AND T1.Col2=T2.Column2) 
     OR (T1.Col1=T2.Column2 AND T1.Col2=T2.Column1)
```

Result:

```
Col1    Col2    Result
---------------------------
A       B       Do Not Show
C       D       Do Not Show
E       G       Show
P       Q       Show
Z       F       Show
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c318/5)